# bg img (png файл) не прижимается к низу страницы. Он просто не появляется на странице

Tags: html, css

Суть в том чтобы картинка была прижата низу страницы, без прокруток и при этом на нее не налазил контент. Путь к файлу проверял.

```css
.fig-buttom {
  background: #2f1ce4 url("../lpng") no-repeat fixed bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fig-buttom"></div>
```

Comment: Откройте инспектор кода и посмотрите на размеры вашего div-а

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки:

1. Путь к файлу 1.png - пропустили точку
2. Background position - fixed (нельзя задавать)
3. background-size: cover (нельзя задавать) потому что растянет на весь блок

   ```
   .fig-buttom { 
         background: #2f1ce4 url("../1.png") no-repeat center bottom; 
         background-size: 300px; 
         padding-bottom: 300px; 
         width: 300px; 
   }
   ```